# Can we perform scheduling stored procedure with client access?

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Oracle SQL developer client. I tried running my stored procedure and got positive result.

Now, I need to schedule my stored procedure. I followed the correct steps to schedule the execution of the stored procedure. But, the procedures are not executed at the scheduled time.

I have doubts on the permissions of the client database. Can we schedule a stored procedure with client access? Otherwise, Is there any way to check that the existing client have the permissions to perform scheduling?

Comment: What were "the correct steps" that you followed?  I'm guessing that you were told to use either the `dbms_job` or `dbms_scheduler` package to schedule the procedure to run.  What, exactly, happened at the scheduled time?  Did the execution fail?  What queries are you running to see that the job is scheduled, whether it ran, etc?  What is the `job_queue_processes` parameter set to?

Comment: I didn't get any response in the logs on the scheduled time. So, I tried executing it immediately using the same scheduling method. In that, I am getting the result log as "SUCCESS" but it didn't do the action to be performed.

Comment: I'm still completely lost as to what you're doing.  How are you scheduling the procedure?  Are you using `dbms_job`?  `dbms_scheduler`?  Something else?  What logs are you looking at?  The `dbms_scheduler` job logs?  Some tables that your code writes to?  Something else?  Where are you seeing "SUCCESS"?